# Does LauncherDiscoveryRequest only match against tests annotated with org.junit.jupiter.api.Test?

Tags: junit5

I've got an existing codebase with JUnit4 tests (annotated with [org.junit.Test](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Test.html)).   I now need to add new JUnit5 tests, while ideally leaving the JUnit4 tests unchanged for now.

I've experimented with using [LauncherDiscoveryRequest](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/launcher/LauncherDiscoveryRequest.html) to discover the tests and trigger their execution.  It seems that it only discovers tests annoated with [org.junit.jupiter.api.Test](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Test.html), and ignores those annotated with [org.junit.Test](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Test.html).  Is that correct, or have I misconfigured something?

Comment: Is "vintage", i.e. "junit-vintage-engine", in your class-path? That engine takes care of JUnit 4 @Test annotations.

Comment: Yes, and I can see a call to the TestExecutionListener.executionStarted() method for the 'JUnit Vintage' component, but no subsequent calls for org.junit.Test annotated tests.

Comment: Please open an issue at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues with a small source code demo that shows that behaviour. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sormuras For the demo code I created a modified version of the junit5-maven-consumer sample.  As expected, if junit-jupiter-engine is the only engine in the classpath, then only JUnit5 tests get discovered and if junit-vintage-engine is the only engine in the classpath, then only JUnit4 tests get discovered.  If both are present, then whichever one occurs first in the pom.xml file's dependencies section gets used and the other gets ignored.  So it seems it's not possible to discover both JUnit5 and JUnit4 tests at the same time. Is that expected, or should I open an issue?

Comment: I guess, you modified too much. See https://travis-ci.org/junit-team/junit5-samples/jobs/277924630#L1075 JUnit 4 and 5 test running side-by-side.

Comment: @Sormuras I can get those same results with my modifications if I run 'mvnw clean test', but that's not using LaucherDiscoveryRequest.   The issue is where I build a shaded jar file which has a main class that uses LauncherDiscoveryRequest to discover the tests.  It doesn't seem possible for LauncherDiscoveryRequest to discover both JUnit5 and JUnit4 tests, it seems it has to be one or the other.   Is that what you expect, or is it an issue?

Comment: The test target uses the ConsoleLauncher which uses LauncherDiscoveryRequests internally as well. See how we build the standalone "uberjar", especially don't forget to merge the META-INF/service files: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-platform-console-standalone/junit-platform-console-standalone.gradle#L71